# How to create a nav with a drop-down that overlaps the main content

Tags: html, css, nav

I have been trying to create a sub-menu in my nav. I have created a second `<ul>` in my `<li>`. As I hover over the `<li>` this gets a bigger width (no clue why) and the second problem I have is, this sub-menu is inside my nav itself. So my just gets a bigger `height`.

This is what I get:
[image: This is what I get]

What I am trying to achieve (made with paint):
[image]

I have made a jsfiddle, this is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qp0k7rsu/#&togetherjs=fUSEKu97tO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just have to add `position: absolute;` on your `#dropdown` rule in the css. I've updated the jsfiddle with a couple of minor changes to your `#dropdown`

EDIT: updated jsfiddle to include your second request just had to add a rule on hover for `#overOns` (see blow), no need for jquery/javascript. Since the `#dropdown` is inside the `overOns` element, this is all you need

```
#overOns:hover {
  background-color: #bd003a;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qp0k7rsu/3/

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make the li "Over ons" active when the user is on the sub-menu? So the background changes

Comment: @Blank see my answer below for how to do that.

Comment: @Blank see my edit, there is no need to use javascript/jquery for that!

Comment: @philr +1 Didn't think about that!  Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the solution by @philr, the fiddle linked to below also keeps the "Over Ons" header with the active background while the user hovers over the sub-menu.

Some JavaScript was required to achieve that functionality, but not much.  All I added were two event listeners.

**https://jsfiddle.net/freginold/zr7vsp3z/**

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var overOns = document.getElementById('overOns');

dropdown.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    overOns.style.backgroundColor = "#bd003a";
});

dropdown.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    overOns.style.backgroundColor = "#da0043";
});
```

Comment: this works in the fiddle, but it doesn't work when i place it in my file.. How come?

Comment: did you add it as a separate JavaScript file, or in a `<script>` tag in your HTML?

Comment: @Blank I would suggest using philr's idea... it avoids the need for JavaScript and it's much cleaner.